# Spring boot maven build not including artifact version in final jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jar

On building my spring boot app using `mvn clean package`, the final artifact that is getting built, myapp.jar, is not having the version number included in the jar name.
**What change should i do to get the artifact verion number to be part of jar.**
The relevant part of pom.xml is as below -

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycomp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>

    <name>myapp</name>
    <description>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </description>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

        <springboot.version>2.5.6</springboot.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${springboot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.12</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <finalName>gitlab-finder</finalName>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2</version>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${springboot.version}</version>
                
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

**Note:** I created a new spring boot project using spring starter (through sts), and for this new project the jar has artifact version included in the jar name by default.  So wondering if this a default feature why is this not the case for my project (by the way, i am maintainer of this project not the creator but i have to add this feature of including version number to jar name.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are overwriting the default behaviour of generating project names. This is because you define the `finalName` tag.

From the [docs](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#BaseBuild_Element):

> **finalName**: This is the name of the bundled project when it is finally built (sans the file extension, for example: my-project-1.0.jar). It defaults to ${artifactId}-${version}.

In your case it is defined as `<finalName>gitlab-finder</finalName>` which does not contain the version of the project. You either add `${version}` to it `<finalName>gitlab-finder-${version}</finalName>` or remove the `finalName` tag.